# Is clock_nanosleep affected by adjtime and NTP?

Tags: linux, time, timer, linux-kernel

Usually `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW` is used for obtaining a clock that is not affected by NTP or `adjtime()`. However `clock_nanosleep()` doesn't support `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW` and trying to use it anyway will result in return code 95 *Operation not supported* (Kernel 4.6.0).

Does `clock_nanosleep()` somehow take these clock adjustments into account or will the sleep time be affected by it?

What are the alternatives if a sleeping time is required which should not be affected by clock adjustments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW` never had support for `clock_nanosleep()` since it [was introduced](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=2d42244ae71d6c7b0884b5664cf2eda30fb2ae68) in Linux 2.6.28. It was also [explicitly fixed](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=70d715fd0597f18528f389b5ac59102263067744) to not have this support in 2.6.32 [because of oopses](https://lkml.org/lkml/2009/8/4/28). The code had been refactored several times after that, but still there is no support for `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW` in `clock_nanosleep()` and I wasn't able to find any comments on *why* is that.

At the very minimum, the fact that there was a patch that explicitly disabled this functionality and it passed all reviews tells us that it doesn't look like a big problem for kernel developers. So, at the moment (4.7) [the only things `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW` supports](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/time/posix-timers.c?h=v4.7#n309) are `clock_getres()` and `clock_gettime()`.

Speaking of adjustments, as [already noted by Rich](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39064645/165063) `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` *is* subject to rate adjustments just by the nature of this clock. This happens because [`hrtimer_interrupt()`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/time/hrtimer.c?h=v4.7#n1313) runs its queues with adjusted monotonic time value ([ktime_get_update_offsets_now()](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/time/timekeeping.c?h=v4.7#n2200)->[timekeeping_get_ns()](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/time/timekeeping.c?h=v4.7#n314)->[timekeeping_delta_to_ns()](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/time/timekeeping.c?h=v4.7#n302) and that operates with `xtime_nsec` which is [subject to adjustment](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/time/timekeeping.c?h=v4.7#n1830)). Actually, looking at this code I'm probably no longer surprised that `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW` has no support for `clock_nanosleep()` (and probably won't have it in future) — adjusted monotonic clock usage seems to be the basis for hrtimers.

As for alternatives, I think there are none. [`nanosleep()` uses the same `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/time/hrtimer.c?h=v4.7#n1576), [`setitimer()` has its own set of timers](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setitimer), [`alarm()` uses ITIMER_REAL (same as `setitimer()`)](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/time/timer.c?h=v4.7#n1442), that ([with some indirection](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/time/itimer.c?h=v4.7#n207)) is [also our good old friend `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/fork.c?h=v4.7#n1180). What else do we have? I guess nothing.

As an unrelated side note, there is an interesting observation in that if you call `clock_nanosleep()` for relative interval (that is not `TIMER_ABSTIME`) then [`CLOCK_REALTIME` actually becomes a synonym for `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/time/hrtimer.c?h=v4.7#n1125).

Comment: Very helpful answer, thanks for your effort. So according to [Rich's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39064645/165063) `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` is more accurate than `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW` and thus preferable for small sleeps, especially since `adjtime` adjustments are negligible for short intervals.