# Clock_nanosleep() does not yet support CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW. How to deal with this?

Tags: c, timer

Currently `clock_nanosleep` with CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW on Debian Jessie returns EOPNOTSUPP.

How to work around the issue and compensate for possible NTP adjustments which might get applied to CLOCK_MONOTONIC in the timer loop?

Is `clock_nanosleep` itself also affected by NTP adjustments? If adjustments happen while sleeping, will `clock_nanosleep` sleep longer that expected?

And should I be worried at all about possible CLOCK_MONOTONIC NTP adjustments in my specific case? What would be the largest possible "time jump" applied by NTP to CLOCK_MONOTONIC, considering that my code will be running on a system without real-time clock and it might lose Internet connection from time to time?

The long story. I'm using a simple loop to emulate audio file playback and I need to maintain consistent playback position.

`clock_nanosleep` with TIMER_ABSTIME flag seems to be doing the job fine, but I'm not sure if CLOCK_MONOTONIC is enough to avoid noticeable jumps in playback position.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &deadline);

// run until asked to stop
while(!need_quit(stop_mutex_signal)) {

    // do stuff ...

    // add time ms to previous deadline
    deadline.tv_nsec += device->periodTime * NANOSECONDS_PER_MILLISEC;

    // normalize the time to account for the second boundary
    if(deadline.tv_nsec >= NANOSECONDS_PER_SEC) {
        deadline.tv_nsec -= NANOSECONDS_PER_SEC;
        deadline.tv_sec++;
    }

    if(clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, TIMER_ABSTIME, &deadline, NULL) != 0)
    {
        // something happened - error or exit signal, cannot continue
        return;
    }
}
```

I'm curious, why support for CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW in `clock_nanosleep` is not yet implemented? Does it mean that CLOCK_MONOTONIC is enough for most cases, even for audio/video synchronization?

Comment: Why don't you write a simple test program and try running it to see what happens when you set the system clock backward when sleeping?

Comment: I already did that and didn't notice anything critical. But I'm new to Linux/Unix, so I'm not sure if I don't miss anything. Murphy always gets you - if something seems simple and is working fine, then it, most probably, has some hidden skeletons... Especially true in programming when using unfamiliar API.

Answer (score 6):

`CLOCK_MONOTONIC` is monotonic. It is not subject to any jumps, from ntp or otherwise. The only thing it is subject to is drift rate adjustment which is usually done by ntpd via `adjtime` or similar. For short intervals this adjustment is not going to be visible at all. In any case, as long as your system is not maliciously configured, it's much **more accurate** than `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW`. As an example (made up numbers but they're probably in the realm of reasonableness) `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW` might be running at a rate of 999950000 nanoseconds per actual second and `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` at a rate of 1000001000 nanoseconds per actual second.